# What should I do if facebook ignore fake news?

Tags: internet

Now, our state is in war zone and people are dying daily because of war. Government and Arakan Army are fighting with heavy weapons. No Journalist are allowed to enters, we have 17 divisions in our state and only 3 divisions access internet and telephone. Government cut off those. So, here is my question.

There are so many fake news on facebook about your state current situation. We reported facebook team and they reply "It doesn't go community standard".

**So, Where should I report if we have prove? If facebook ignores "fake news".**

Normally, in my point of views,  fake news on internet is usual but people are dying and world need to know truth.

Comment: don't take your news from facebook I suppose

Answer (score 4):

Facebook's local jurisdiction is the US.  In the US, making false statements isn't generally illegal or tortious, as they are protected by the First Amendment to the US Constitution.  So, Facebook isn't under any legal pressure to remove posts that are posting false information.  It sounds like you've already asked them to remove the posts and they refused, so at this point you do not seem to have any procedural recourse with Facebook.  It's possible your country or the country the person is posting from lacks free speech protections and would either prosecute or allow suits against someone posting false information, if that's the case you could try to get the local equivalent of a prosecutor to prosecute them.  I realize that is unlikely to happen, the reality is that coordinated fake news on the Internet is still something that platforms are figuring out how to deal with fairly.